# Define and evaluate reusable logical expressions in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

Is there a way to express a logical expression in python and then evaluate it on an array of values?

For example, say we have the following array of value pairs that represent possible values for `x` and `y`:

```
a = [[True, True], [True, False], [False, True]]
```

Given an expression, e.g., `x and y`, we can evaluate it for each of the pairs (getting back `True, False, False`). We could write a function and call it for each of the pairs, however I'd like to generate in runtime a series of expressions and evaluate them. Is there a clean Pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What would your input actually look like? I understand the `x and y` example, and I think you want to automate the process for multiple inputs?

Comment: A generator will produce multiple expressions. Say, `x`, `x and y`, and `x or y`. I'm writing the generator, so it can produce those in whatever format makes sense.